# In Libre Calc, how to convert the cell having "4 hours 15 minutes" to decimal values and place it in another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

In Libre Calc, how to convert the cell having "4 hours 15 minutes" to decimal values and place it in another cell?

Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "decimal values" do you want to get 4.25 for your example?

If that's a text value in A1 try this formula in B1

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," hours ",":")," minutes","")*24`

format B1 as number

Note: that works in Excel - I don't have access to libreoffice at the moment to check